# Load New Sections of Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to load certain content to a viewcontroller when the user swipes to the right or the left but still keeps specific content. For example, the image demonstrates:

[image]

As you can see, the upper 1/3 of the view controller (i.e. the blue rectangular background) stays the same when the user swipes to the right. However, below that, the background, buttons, etc. change on the second page.

Would it be possible to accomplish this with a page view controller, like what is demonstrated [here](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/)? How else might this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly a `UIPageViewController` would be the simplest to implement. [There is a great tutorial over at AppCoda](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/).

[image: AppCoda UIPageViewController Tutorial]

Alternately, you could just use a container view on the bottom portion and use a `UIViewController` with a `UIScrollView` on it with paging turned on and a `UIPageControl` to provide visual indicators.

You really need to understand about view controllers, views and containment. [Apple's View Controller Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW1) is a good first stop for learning.

[image: UIViewController]

Comment: Is there a tutorial or some code that I could reference for the `UIPageViewController` method?